# Why am I getting a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" with a SignalR clientside callback?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I'm running SignalR 1.0.1 and am trying to hook into some callbacks in my clientside javascript.

Consider the following code blocks:

```
var hub = $.connection.FooHub;

hub.disconnected(function () {                
            log("Server has disconnected");
        });

hub.received(function (data) {                
            log("Data Received");
        });
```

In both instances, I get the following error message:
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Clearly, I'm missing something here.
Can someone help point me out in the right direction?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: do you have the autogenerated hubs included in the page, it should look something like this `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
hub.disconnected = function () {                
        log("Server has disconnected");
    };

hub.received = function (data) {                
        log("Data Received");
    };
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It very well may prevent the TypeError, but the `disconnected` and `received` methods are existing methods meant for attaching even handlers like JohnB does in his question. These methods are *not* called when their respective events are fired. In fact, these methods will *never* be called by SignalR since they are meant to be called by the API consumer. ahmelsayed is probably correct about needing to include the "/signalr/hubs" script. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: I'm a little confused by response. I got around the TypeError by the following:$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
  alert('Disconnected');
 });
I have one for "Received" as well. It gets fired whenever data is received in the client. The Disconnect() does not get fired.

What I'm really trying to achieve is add the callback. How do I go about doing this? We have an MVC based web app with signalr embedded.

Answer (score 0):

The hub proxy is created using camel-case (as is appropriate for JavaScript). So, if you define FooHub on your server, you access it on the client using $.connection.fooHub, not $.connection.FooHub.

Comment: My fault on the example. I fat fingered FooHub, I really did mean fooHub.

Comment: For method names, both are valid (automatic translation), at least in the latest SignalR versions. However for hub names only the camel case works.